# Find what is writing to the Output window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am debugging a huge enterprise system with a WCF service and fat windows Winforms client. I am running the whole stack in debug.

Something is writing to the Output window repeatedly during a long running process that I am determined to find. I have added new breakpoints to `System.Console.Write`, `System.Console.WriteLine`, `System.Diagnostic.Debug.Write` and `System.Diagnostic.Debug.Write` and all hit when other things use them but none are hitting for this.

What other ways of writing to output am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I found it, I didn't think it could be but a breakpoint found `System.Diagnostic.Debug.Print` also just writes to output.